Hashable and ordered enums to describe states of a process
I am wiriting am application which needs to store information about an industrial process where products go through the following, strictly sequential phases:
Admission, Processing, QC, Delivery
Plus two exceptional states: Unrecognized, Inactive
Since these states are well-known and not supposed to change during execution, I decided to model them using enums, with some improvements to make them easier to work with:

make them hashable (so that they can be used as dict keys)
make the sequential phases comparable by their order


util.py
class _IndexEnum(Enum):
    """
    enum where every member is associated with an index representing its declaration order, stored within the _member_index_ attribute
    """

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for i, member in enumerate(cls):
            member._member_index_ = i
    
    #due to immutability of enums, equality can be reduced to a comparison of _member_id_
    #(self and other have same _member_id_ iff they refer to the same instance)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            if self._member_index_ == other._member_index_:
                assert self is other, \
                f"Can't have more than one member with same _member_id_ ({self}, {other})"
                return True

class HashableEnum(_IndexEnum):
    """
    enum whose members are hashable. If the member's class is not hashable, an implementation is provided
    """
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

        if cls.__hash__ is None:
            cls.__hash__ = HashableEnum.__hash__

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._member_index_)

@total_ordering  
class SequenceEnum(_IndexEnum):
    """
    enum whose members are comparable by their declaration order
    """
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self._member_index_ < other._member_index_
        return NotImplemented

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self._member_index_ == other._member_index_ ```



models.py
@dataclass 
class _ProcessState:
    """
    represents a state within the industrial process
    """
    display_name:   str

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name

class ProcessStateEnum(_ProcessState, Enum):
    """
    enum whose members represent states within the industrial process.
    """

    #the state's display name is implicitly generated from enum member name without underscores
    @override
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return name.lower().replace('_', ' ')

class ProcessExceptions(HashableEnum, ProcessStateEnum):
    """
    exceptional states of the industrial process, outside of the normal flow
    """
    UNRECOGNIZED = auto()
    INACTIVE = auto()

#Order is important! ProcessStateEnum must be last so that its implementation of _generate_next_value_ is called 
class ProcessPhases(HashableEnum, SequenceEnum, ProcessStateEnum):
    """
    normal phases of the industrial process, strictly sequential and comparable by their order within the process
    """
    ADMISSION = auto()
    PROCESSING = auto()
    QC = auto()
    DELIVERY = auto() 



views.py
#associates a symbolic color to each state, used to make all views color coded
state_to_color = defaultdict(
    #default color
    lambda: "#B3B3B3", {
    ProcessPhases.ADMISSION :  "#5301b1"
    ProcessPhases.PROCESSING : "#F4B704",
    ProcessPhases.QC :         "#FD0002",
    ProcessPhases.DELIVERY :   "#7FB857" }) 


Possible future requirements and how I plan to handle them:

the addition of substates: create a ProcessSubstates enum to use as field for _ProcessState

non-sequential states (unlikely): implement state design pattern over _ProcessState (may have to give up on ordering and SequenceEnum)

add/remove states at runtime (even more unlikely): _ProcessState instances can be defined outside of enums, and still be able to interact with those who are enum members.


My main concerns are maintainability and readability/ease of use in other parts of the codebase.

This smacks of over-engineering, especially since you (correctly) are concerned about maintainability.
I have good news! There's another, much simpler, style that meets your objectives of hashability and strict sequence:
class ProcessPhase(IntEnum):
    ADMISSION = 1
    PROCESSING = 2
    QC = 3
    DELIVERY = 4

You can still define your state_to_colour as a dictionary, although I can't see why it would need to be a defaultdict.

When using dict you would have to overload __missing__ to be the lambda: "#B3B3B3" code to have equivalent code. Providing the defaultfactory to defaultdict saves a subclass which is fairly pointless.

After pondering over my requirements, I have got to admit that over-engineering definitely hits the mark.
The only thing the IntEnum is missing is the string representation part, but I now relalize that responsibility belonged to views.py in the first place (why not put a state_to_str dict in there as well).
Anywhere else inside the code should refer to the states by their int value

In addition to the reasons @Peilonrayz pointed out, having a default color keeps my code from breaking anytime I add a new state without specifying a corresponding colour  (the bothersome alternative would be to handle KeyErrors anywhere the dict is used)

@Afelium or use dict.get(key, default_value) instead of indexing.
